# Load files with the same name in data flow Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use data flow in Azure data factory And I set as source dataset files with the same name. The files have named “name_date1” end “name_date2”. I want that data flow  load in sink db only data of file  “name_date1”.
How is it possible?

Comment: Are you using multiple sources here? If you are using a single source, then you can directly point the file path to your source file name_date1

Comment: @BhargavaGunnam-MSFT yes, I’m using multiple sources. I set path “name_*.csv”

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple files being read in your ADF data flow source transformation, you can use the property called "Column to store file name" under Source Options. Provide a name to store the filename and it will become part of your metadata. You can then use a Filter transformation to include only source files with a specific filename by matching on that column that has the file name.

Comment: Is there a method where I can load only data from “name_date1”without specific “name_date1” file?

Comment: can I use foreach and lookup with data flow?